# Angular pipe to suppress sensitive information

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I have created an Angular pipe to suppress the sensitive information like credit cards, bank account, ABA numbers etc.

This is working fine but I would like to know if this is the best possible way to implement the logic.

Here is the Typescript code for pipe logic.

```
export class SuppressInfoPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(valueToSupress: string, unSuppressedCount?: number): string {


    let suppressedOutput = '';

    const valueToRemainUnsuppressed =
    valueToSupress.substring(valueToSupress.length - unSuppressedCount, valueToSupress.length);

    let astariskLength = valueToSupress.length - unSuppressedCount;

    for ( let i = 0; i < astariskLength; i++) {
     suppressedOutput = suppressedOutput.concat('*');
    }
    suppressedOutput = suppressedOutput.concat(valueToRemainUnsuppressed);

    return suppressedOutput;
  }

}
```

it takes the string input and the number of character they will no be hidden and then return the suppressed output.

Comments and suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the for loop to generate the "suppressed string".

My approach would be:

```
export class SuppressInfoPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(valueToSupress: string, unSuppressedCount = 0): string {
    const suppressedCount = valueToSupress.length - unSuppressedCount;
    const valueToRemainUnsuppressed =
    valueToSupress.substring(suppressedCount, valueToSupress.length);

    return Array(suppressedCount + 1).join('*') + valueToRemainUnsuppressed; // suppressedCount + 1: since join will a string of length "suppressedCount"
  }
}
```

In this case:

```
Array(n) will return an array of length n.
```

[image]

`.join("*")` will join the list and return a string equivalent of length n-1.

Comment: That's much better. Only thing I want to confirm is this changing the type of Array object when returning just like JavaScript does to variables depending upon the data being assigned ?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I got your point :) . Thanks for adding explanation to your answer.